# Redshift UDF aggregate or window error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have written the following function

```
create function sevRun (text,text,int)
returns int stable as $$
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM (SELECT case_id
          FROM dbname.tablename
         WHERE create_date >= TO_DATE('2017-' || $1::text || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
           AND create_date < TO_DATE('2017-' || $2::text || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
           AND min_impact <= $3
           AND assigned_to_group IN ('listitem','listitem','....')
       ) inline_view
$$language sql;
```

when I call the function `select sevRun ('01','02',2);` I get the following error

`Invalid operation: The select expression can not have aggregate or window function.;`

I'm trying to create a function that I can call multiple times and change the month to suit

Comment: From the error i would say that the `COUNT` is the Problem, since that is the only Aggregate function in there.

Comment: Your function works for me on PostgreSQL 9.6 if I replace `RETURNS int` with `RETURNS bigint`.

Comment: this is on redshift which is based on postgre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select from the table inside the SQL UDF in Redshift. The only allowed functions are scalar functions that operate on the input parameters and return the output.

UPD: Redshift now support stored procedures in plpgsql. [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html)

Comment: Is there any other way to store and call queries that are used repetitively in Redshift?

Comment: Redshift now supports stored procedures similarly to other databases (see the answer update).

Answer (score 0):

Why not this query -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbname.tablename
WHERE create_date >= TO_DATE('2017-' || $1::text || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND create_date < TO_DATE('2017-' || $2::text || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND min_impact <= $3
AND assigned_to_group IN ('listitem','listitem','....')
```